# which wmd-editor repository to use

Tags: javascript, github, wmd, wmd-editor, wysiwym

I read that the original [wmd-editor](http://wmd-editor.com) is no longer maintained so there was an effort to reverse engineer it, [hosted on github](http://wiki.github.com/cky/wmd). However this version is not ready because it references a number of undefined functions, for example:

> processHeadings is not defined
>   /static/js/lib/plugins/wmd/showdown.js
>   Line 66

There is also a [version on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/), but the repository is empty.

Does anyone know if there is a successful reverse engineering attempt of wmd-editor with a publicly accessible repository?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [derobbins](http://github.com/derobins/wmd) version is the version I believe most people are using (and the one used here on Stack Overflow).

There are also a number of forks off of the derobbins version that add some additional functionality (ajax loading for example) or other fixes if you're interested, including [mine (MarkEdit)](http://github.com/tstone/jquery-markedit) which is a jQuery re-write of the interface side of WMD editor to add customization and a public API.

Comment: Awesome! I am using JQuery for the rest of my JavaScript, so is it worth using your fork instead?

Comment: If you like jQuery it's certainly worth looking into.  MarkEdit is easily less mature than wmd-editor original, and it has some opinions though which you may or may not like (such as using themeroller CSS).  There's a live demo up if you wanted to try it out before spending time reading the wiki.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Updating as per [2010-02](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357022/what-is-a-good-client-side-markdown-editor/2357145#2357145).</sub>

Take a look at the [wmd-new fork](http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/), the [Stack Overflow fork](http://github.com/derobins/wmd) and one of [the most active branchs](http://github.com/ananthakumaran/wmd/) (from [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35084/is-there-an-official-stackoverflow-version-of-wmd-editor-available-for-download)).